# Converting javascript require to ES6 import

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, passport.js

How would a require string like this be converted into ES6 import syntax?

const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;

Comment: `import { GoogleStrategy } from 'passport-google-oauth20/Strategy'` I think? If it supports such a thing. ...

Comment: Their doc still uses this :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exact equivalent which will preserve the naming would be

```
import { Strategy as GoogleStrategy } from 'passport-google-oauth20';
```

You can read about it in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_an_export_with_a_more_convenient_alias).